# Mapbox-GL: Event handlers do not have access to useSelector() variables

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to dispatch a GeoJSON (grocers) from my Redux but I am unable to access it in the map.on('load') () => { map.addSource('bronx-grocers'). When I console.log(grocers) after the second useEffect() the data appears, but if I console.log(grocers) in the map.on('load') it returns null.

```js
const Home = () => {
  const grocers = useSelector(state => state.grocers)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)
  const mapContainer = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(gotGrocers())
  }, [])

  useEffect(
    () => {
      mapboxgl.accessToken =
        'personal-token'
      const initializeMap = ({setMap, mapContainer}) => {
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: mapContainer.current,
          style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
          center: coordinates,
          zoom: zoomLevel
        })

        map.on('load', () => {
          setMap(map)
          map.resize()
        })

        map.on('load', () => {
          map.addSource('bronx-grocers', {
            type: 'geojson',
            data: GeoJSON
          })
          map.addLayer(pointStyles)
        })
      }

      if (!map) initializeMap({setMap, mapContainer})
    },
    [map]
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          Longitude: {coordinates[0]} | Latitude: {coordinates[1]} | Zoom Level:{' '}
          {zoomLevel}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ref={el => (mapContainer.current = el)} style={mapStyles} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Could you please update your code so that the code snippet runs? Also, could you show more detail about the console logging you added?